# NGXS doesn't work when update to Angular 9 with Ivy enabled

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9, ngxs, angular-ivy

I'm trying to update my application to Angular 9. Everything runs fine when I disable the Ivy, but with Ivy enabled the application doesn't finish the serve task correctly:

**My component:**

```js
choosePlan(plan: IPlan) {
  if (!this.isAddressValid()) {
    this._toastService.error('Informe o seu CEP!', '', { positionClass: 'toast-top-right' });
  } else {
    this._actions$
      .pipe(
        ofActionSuccessful(this.addItem(plan)),
        tap(() => this._clearUtms())
      )
      .subscribe(() => this._router.navigate([`/checkout/carrinho/${this.cart.id}`]));
  }
}
```

**My state:**

```js
@State<CartStateModel>({
  name: 'cart',
  defaults: {
    cart: {},
  },
})
@Injectable()
export class CartState {
  @Action(Cart.AddItem)
  addItem(ctx: StateContext<CartStateModel>, action: Cart.AddItem): Observable<ICart> {
    const currentState = ctx.getState();

    return zip(this.address$, this.shipping$).pipe(
      mergeMap((obs: [IAddress, IShippingType]) =>
        this._cartService.addItemToCart(
          currentState.cart.id,
          action.itemToAdd,
          obs[0].cep,
          obs[1].shippingMethodId
        )
      ),
      tap((cart: ICart) => ctx.setState({ cart: cart })),
      take(1),
      catchError((error: any) => throwError(error))
    );
  }
}
```

**My action:**

```js
export class Create {
  static readonly type = '[Cart] Create';
  constructor(public itemToAdd: ICartItemToAdd) {}
}
```

**The error of VS Code from Typescript:**
Here the image: [error from typescript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2Tai.png)

```sh
Argument of type 'AddItem | Create' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ActionType'.
  Type 'AddItem' is not assignable to type 'ActionType'.
    Property 'type' is missing in type 'AddItem' but required in type '{ type: string; }'.
```

**The error of angular cli:**

```sh
: Compiled successfully.

ERROR in src/app/core/product/pages/product.component.ts:87:30 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Create | AddItem' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ActionType'.
  Type 'Create' is not assignable to type 'ActionType'.
    Property 'type' is missing in type 'Create' but required in type '{ type: string; }'.

87           ofActionSuccessful(this.addItem(plan)),
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@ngxs/store/src/actions/symbols.d.ts:6:5
    6     type: string;
          ~~~~
    'type' is declared here.
src/app/core/checkout/pages/cart/cart.component.ts:67:46 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'RemoveItem' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ActionType'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type 'RemoveItem' but required in type '{ type: string; }'.

67       this._actions$.pipe(ofActionSuccessful(action)).subscribe(() => this._getCart());
                                                ~~~~~~

  node_modules/@ngxs/store/src/actions/symbols.d.ts:6:5
    6     type: string;
          ~~~~
    'type' is declared here.
src/app/core/checkout/pages/cart/cart.component.ts:72:44 - error TS2345: Argument of type '(Reset | Reset | Reset | Reset | Reset | Reset | Reset)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ActionType'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type '(Reset | Reset | Reset | Reset | Reset | Reset | Reset)[]' but required in type '{ type: string; }'.

72     this._actions$.pipe(ofActionSuccessful(this._checkoutFacadeService.resetStates())).subscribe();
                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@ngxs/store/src/actions/symbols.d.ts:6:5
    6     type: string;
          ~~~~
    'type' is declared here.
src/app/core/checkout/guards/cart-resume/cart-resume.resolver.ts:22:27 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Fetch' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ActionType'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type 'Fetch' but required in type '{ type: string; }'.

22         ofActionCompleted(cartAction),
                              ~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@ngxs/store/src/actions/symbols.d.ts:6:5
    6     type: string;
          ~~~~
    'type' is declared here.
```

**The error is about the type of Action:**

```js
export namespace Cart {
  export class Create {
    static readonly type = '[Cart] Create';
    constructor(public itemToAdd: ICartItemToAdd) {}
  }
}
```

**One of these errors is gone when I remove the line:**

```js
static readonly type = '[Cart] Create';
```

But I can't, because the Actions need a type.

**My package follow below with version of packages:**

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^9.1.13",
  "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
  "@angular/common": "^9.1.13",
  "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.13",
  "@angular/core": "^9.1.13",
  "@angular/forms": "^9.1.13",
  "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
  "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "9.2.4",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.13",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.13",
  "@angular/router": "^9.1.13",
  "@angular/service-worker": "^9.1.13",
  "@celulardireto/ui-lib": "^0.34.3",
  "@glidejs/glide": "^3.3.0",
  "@ngxs-labs/dispatch-decorator": "^2.1.0",
  "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.6.0",
  "@ngxs/logger-plugin": "^3.6.0",
  "@ngxs/storage-plugin": "^3.6.0",
  "@ngxs/store": "^3.6.0",
  "@types/scriptjs": "^0.0.2",
  "apollo-angular": "^1.10.0",
  "apollo-angular-link-http": "^1.11.0",
  "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.6",
  "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
  "apollo-link": "^1.2.14",
  "card-validator": "^6.2.0",
  "core-js": "^2.5.4",
  "date-fns": "^2.4.1",
  "graphql": "^15.3.0",
  "graphql-tag": "^2.11.0",
  "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
  "karma-spec-reporter": "^0.0.32",
  "lazysizes": "^5.2.0",
  "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
  "moment": "2.24.0",
  "ng-recaptcha": "^7.0.1",
  "ngx-device-detector": "^2.0.5",
  "ngx-mask": "9.1.4",
  "ngx-toastr": "11.3.3",
  "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
  "remove-accents": "^0.4.2",
  "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
  "scriptjs": "^2.5.9",
  "string-mask": "0.3.0",
  "tslib": "^1.10.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
},
```

What can I do?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the action in the action stream (`_actions$`) correctly.

Try changing

```
ofActionSuccessful(this.addItem(plan)),
```

to

```
ofActionSuccessful(Cart.AddItem),
```

Comment: Interesting. The error was gone. But how the action AddItem can know the plan if I don't pass on params?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, I think you're wanting to know when an action with a particular payload is successful? If that's the case you'd first check ofActionSuccessful(Cart.AddItem), then filter based on the action. You didn't show your AddItem action, but I'm assuming you have payload of 'plan' So your pipe could be: `.pipe(ofActionSuccessful(Cart.AddItem), filter(action => action.plan === plan))` You might still run into issues though.